# ¿La habitación o el habitación?

Tags: gramática, artículos

En el libro de gramática la regla de artículos definidos especifica uso del "el" cuando el sonido de la primer sílaba del substantivo es "a", pero la respuesta del ejercicio es "la habitación". Estoy confundido.

Answer (score 5):

La forma correcta es:

- **la** habitación

La regla por la cual se usa artículo masculino delante de sustantivo femenino corresponde cuando la "a" o "ha" del sustantivo está acentuada. En "habitación", la sílaba acentuada es "ción", no "ha". Algunos ejemplos de sustantivos femeninos que empiezan con "a" o "ha" acentuadas son:

- el águila (blanca)
- el hacha (afilada)
- el agua (clara)
- el alma (pura)

Esta regla aplica a los artículos "la" y "una" (delante de sustantivos femeninos iniciados con "a" o "ha" tónicas se usan "el" y "un") y a los adjetivos indefinidos "alguna" y "ninguna" (delante de los sustantivos detallados se usan "algún" y "ningún).

Fuente: http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Sustantivos%20femeninos%20con%20a-%20o%20ha-%20t%C3%B3nicas.htm

Comment: Muchas gracias!